# Bootstrap Container Centering

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

My form is not centered on my page. See below my html file and the output. How do I center my view?

[image]

Herewith my html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class='row justify-content-center'>
    <div class='col'>
    <p></p>

        <h1>Member Details: </h1>
            <p>Name: JP</p>
            <p>Surname: Roux</p>
            <p>ID Nr: 7604195133089</p>
            <p>Mobile Nr: 0741115552</p>
            <p>Email: jp@test.com</p>
            <p>D.O.B: 1976-04-19</p>
            <p>Language: Afrikaans</p> 
            <p>Interests:
                <ul>
                    <li>Tennis</li>
                    <li>Squash</li>
                </ul>
            </p>
            <p>Created At: 2018-06-06 09:31:31</p>
        <div class="page-header">
        <a href="http://tomcrud.test:8080/members/14/edit" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example in a code snippet? You can copy the HTML code from the browser directly, and if there's any CSS other than the one coming from Bootstrap, copy it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your form like below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='row justify-content-center'>
    <div class='col-6 border border-primary'>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
        <br> Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y56nbu4k/).

Comment: That didn't work. My actual form fields are wrapped in this: <div class="form-group">content</div>. Do you think the .form-group might be the issue? If so, what else would you recommend to wrap the form fields in?

Comment: Then show the actual HTML. What you have shown is not telling your actual structure.

Answer (score 0):

Never use **`justify-content-center`** for the row. If you want to align center content of a column ,  use **`d-flex`** and **`justify-content-center`** for the `column` and wrap its content with a **`w-auto`** div.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col d-flex justify-content-center'>
      <div class="w-auto">
        <p></p>

        <h1>Member Details: </h1>
        <p>Name: JP</p>
        <p>Surname: Roux</p>
        <p>ID Nr: 7604195133089</p>
        <p>Mobile Nr: 0741115552</p>
        <p>Email: jp@test.com</p>
        <p>D.O.B: 1976-04-19</p>
        <p>Language: Afrikaans</p> 
        <p>Interests:
        <ul>
          <li>Tennis</li>
          <li>Squash</li>
        </ul>
        </p>
      <p>Created At: 2018-06-06 09:31:31</p>
      <div class="page-header">
        <a href="http://tomcrud.test:8080/members/14/edit" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKBNKY

---

Centered form

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col d-flex justify-content-center'>
      <form class="w-auto">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKWVqV

---

Using `w-auto` is unnecessary. If you wish, you can omit.